# How can I find nuget package installation folder programmaticaly ? (.NET Core - Cross Platform)

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core

Is there anyway for find .nuget folder and all related folders ? such as

1. C:\Users\ ... \.nuget
2. C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.0

but should be programmatically , Cross platform way , compatible with .NET Core

My problem is finding path of

1. mscorelib.dll and System.Runtime.dll
2. custom installed assemblies like
       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll

for working with Roslyn in .NET Core I need to reference them as list of  MetadataReference.

```
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(...)
```

so I think If I know about all .nuget directories. I can search into them.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the path to your `.nuget` folder programmatically by using this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Configuration/) like this:

```
ISettings settings = Settings.LoadDefaultSettings(null);
string nugetPath = SettingsUtility.GetGlobalPackagesFolder(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to get the NuGet location. You can get the user profile location like below.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

And get ProgramFiles location like below.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
```

Append the remaining path by hard coding.